# SCSS comments/urls

Tags: sass

When I write SCSS, I use `@import` statements like the following:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Abril+Fatface);
```

However, technically, in SCSS the text beyond the `http://` is commented out. Does SCSS/SASS still read the rest of it, even though it is commented out?

Comment: If it is a comment, why would you expect Sass to read it?

Comment: I feel bad that this had a negative vote. The question may sound funny, but it’s noteworthy because the docs _do_ say that this should be valid: "“SCSS” (for “Sassy CSS”) [...] is a superset of CSS’s syntax. This means that every valid CSS stylesheet is valid SCSS as well." Unquoted URIs like this are permitted in CSS and even have a unique token at the lexing level; both the superset claim and the "every valid CSS stylesheet is valid SCSS as well" claim are false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Abril+Fatface");
```